# Prove $X_{\infty} < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales, limsup-and-liminf

From Williams' Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

How exactly do we prove $X_{\infty} < \infty$ a.s.?

$$E[|X_{\infty}|] = E[|\lim X_n|]  = E[|\liminf X_n|] = E[\liminf |X_n|]$$

$$ \le \liminf E[|X_n|] \ \text{by Fatou's Lemma}$$

$$ \le \limsup E[|X_n|]$$

$$ \le \sup E[|X_n|]$$

$$< \infty \ \text{by assumption}$$

$$\to |X_{\infty}| < \infty \ a.s.$$

$$\to X_{\infty} < \infty \ a.s.$$

Comment: If $|Z|=\infty$ on a set having positive measure, then $E|Z|=\infty$, isn't it?

Comment: @d.k.o. Interesting. I never thought about the measure of the set. I just figured if $X=\infty$ a.s. then $E[X]=\infty$. But actually we can weaken hypothesis from a.s. to in a set of positive measure?

Comment: Just another way to see this:

$\mathbb{E}|Z|<\infty \Rightarrow \sum_{n}P\{|Z|>n\}< \infty \Rightarrow P\{|Z|>n\}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. 

$$ \therefore 
P\{|Z|=\infty\}=P\left\{\bigcap_{n}\{|Z|>n\}\right\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\{|Z|>n\}=0.
$$

Comment: @d.k.o. very insightful. Thanks ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct, but notice that you get something stronger than what you state in the last line of your question, indeed $X_{\infty}$ is finite almost surely, which is the same as saying $-\infty < X_{\infty} < \infty$ (and not only $X_{\infty} < \infty$).

To go from the fact that $E(|X_{\infty}|) < \infty$ to the fact that $X_{\infty} \in \mathbb{R}$ a.s., notice that since $X_{\infty} \in L^1$, then Lebesgue's DCT implies that $|X_{\infty}|1_{\{|X_{\infty}| > n\}} \to 0$. In turn, this shows that $\lambda\big(\{w : |X_{\infty}(w)| > n\}\big) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Ah right I forgot a.s. thanks Giovanni ^-^ as for using DCT, is that needed? I think we can just say: If $X=\infty$ a.s. then $E[X] = \infty$. Then take contrapositive? Or is it in the first place that we need DCT or something to say 'if $X=\infty$ a.s. then $E[X] = \infty$'?

Comment: This argument that you suggest works. To be annoyingly pedantic, I would use $|X|$ instead of $X$ to avoid any complication that might arise from the fact that, a priori, it could be that $X_{\infty} = -\infty$ on a set of positive measure. :)